# Defining Brownian motion through Kolmogorov's extension theorem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

In section 2.2. of Oksendal's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540047581) on Stochasic differential equations, he defines Brownian motion by specifying a family of probability measures $\nu_{t_1, \ldots, t_k}(F_1, \ldots, F_k)$ that satisfies conditions of Kolmogorov's extension theorem.

He defines $P = P^{x_0}(B_1 \in F_1, \ldots, B_k \in F_k)$ as integral over $F^\times_k = F_1 \times \cdots \times F_k$

$$
  \int_{F^\times_k} d x_1 \cdots d x_k \prod_{n=1}^k p(t_k-t_{k-1}, x_k-x_{k-1}) 
$$

He then claims

> The Brownian motion thus defined is not unique, i.e. there exists several quadruples $(B_t,\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P^x)$ such the above equation holds.

He then says paths of Brownian motion can be chosen continuous. The needed page is [viewable](http://books.google.com/books?id=VgQDWyihxKYC&lpg=PP1&dq=oksendal%20stochastic%20differential%20equations&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q=the%20brownian%20motion%20thus%20defined&f=false) through Google Books.

So I've been curious to see an example of $(B_t, \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P^x)$ where the paths need not be continuous.

Thank you.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39928/wiener-process-related-counterexample/39932#39932

Comment: @Byron Thanks, it makes perfect sense now. Should I vote to delete this question as a duplicate then ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct protocol is. Your question has a duplicate, but on a different site. I'd leave it up to the moderators, i.e., do nothing.